# Получить изображения из файла Excel с помощью openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

У меня есть excel-файл, в котором есть картинки. Я хочу скопировать эти картинки в презентацию pptx с помощью питона. Вопрос состоит в том, как хранятся картинки в excel-файле и как их считать? openpyxl, как я поняла, картинки не видит.

Comment: По-видимому для решения этой задачи больше подходит VBA, вы не находите?

Comment: поискать решение пробовали? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039535/extract-images-from-excel-file-with-python

Comment: Всем спасибо!
Решиние искать пробовала, но тоода не нашла. Теперь все вижу)